# How do I protect state of current branch without committing?

Tags: git

I'm on a branch that is not ready to be committed, but I want to try something experimental. I want to stash the current state of the branch so it can be recovered if something goes wrong.

When I do git stash, it reverts the branch to the previous commit so the working tree is clean and I can checkout a new experimental branch.  Once on the new branch, I run git stash apply to get the original state back to try my experimental changes.

I make some changes and decide to scrap them.  When I checkout to the first branch and run git stash apply I get an error and all the changes I made in the experimental branch are there.  How do I get the original state before the experimental changes back? Thanks.

For example:

- I created another test repo since I don't really know what I'm doing.  I create a file called `test.txt` and do the initial commit.
- Then do `git checkout -b branch1` and in the text file type "Branch 1 changes".
- Then I do `git stash` to protect the uncommitted state of the current branch.  It deletes what I just did and working tree is clean.
- So I do `git checkout -b experiment`.
- Once there I do `git stash apply` and get the old state back.
- I make changes and decide I don't want them.
- Then I do `git checkout branch1`. Now the changes from the experimental branch are there and when I try to do `git stash apply` to recover the old state, I get an error.

I'd like to know the correct way to simply protect the current state of a branch that is not ready to be committed for the sake of trying something experimental.

Comment: Please show us the exact Git commands you used.  This should not be happening, I think, if you did everything correctly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see my edit for a simple example of what I'm talking about.  I'd like to know the proper way of protecting the state of a branch that's not ready for a commit so I can try something experimental.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Git stage itself was created partly to handle your exact current scenario.

To add to Mark's answer, in your case you may not even have had the need to stash or commit.  You could stage your current completed work, and then try some things out, which would change your working directory, but *not* the stage.  Then, if you were happy with that work, you could add it to the stage.  Otherwise, you could reset the changed files in your working directory to the state when you last staged them.  The workflow would look something like this:

```
# work work work
git add test.txt
# try something out, modify test.txt
# if it didn't work out, then just reset test.txt to the stage
git checkout -- test.txt
```

If the experiment did work out, then you could do `git add` again, add the changes to the stage, and commit.

Comment: Ah, I knew there had to be an easier way.  I just tested it and yes, this is what I was looking for.  I was not aware that checkout could be used in this way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're overthinking this.  If you want to protect the current state, commit.  As long as you don't push the commit, you can remove it from history later, either by doing the subsequent commit with the `--amend` option, or by squashing it using interactive rebase.  (Or other ways, depending on the situation.)

(I'm not saying you *can't* use stash - which is, after all, a mechanism for making temporary commits.  But as you've observed, using stash in this way isn't natural or intuitive, and that's because this isn't exactly what stash was designed for.  Stash is for preserving your WIP and staged changes *while you shift gears to do something else*, which is somewhat different from check-pointing your changes so you can keep working and later revert to the current state.)

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Thank you.